# Words to describe story with an unoriginal, formulaic plot

Tags: word-request, phrase-request, idioms, slang

What are some common words, phrases, idioms or slang to describe a story that has an unoriginal, formulaic plot?

E.g. someone's reaction upon seeing such a TV show is: This is totally _____.

Comment: Cliché?  Stereotypical?

Comment: @VictorBazarov Maybe I am wrong but I have an impression that cliche is mostly used against articles and speeches. Stereotypical looks right but do people actually say it?

Comment: _Run-of-the-mill_: lacking unusual or special aspects; ordinary.

Comment: Rubberstamped?...

Comment: *Hackneyed* is the most common, cliched critique of common, cliched works, I think.

Comment: Saying *This is totally **original**!* will have the effect you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could say that it is **cliché**.

> **cliché** *adj.*
>
> *(in art, literature, drama, etc.)* a trite or hackneyed plot, character development, use of colour, musical expression, etc.

You could also use "**trite**", which basically means "common and overused".